# Arangodb's variable for looping

Tags: arangodb

How can I have an variable that increase over a loop? I tried this AQL and it does not work

```
LET x=0 // I am trying to find a way to increase this one over some conditions
FOR v IN male
Update v WITH (count:x+1) IN male
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in AQL are immutable, so you can't re-assign them. See [docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Operations/Let.html#let)